# distinct-values, contains function failed

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I get distinct @source attribute values of graphml file:

```
<xsl:variable name="sources" 
  select="distinct-values(root()//gml:edge/@source)"/>
```

then, I try to check does this string contains search word or doesnt:

```
<xsl:value-of select="contains($sources, 'N')"/>
```

but, transformation fails with error:

```
Error in XPath 2.0 expression
 Too many items
```

Whats the reason?

PS: fn:matches leads to the same result (error)

Answer (score 2):

The reason for you error is that the `contains` function is a string function, and requires a single string as the first argument. The `distinct-values` function returns a sequence, and if that sequence contains more than one value, then the `contains` function will error.

The way to check if your distinct values contains a specific value is as follows:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$sources[. ='N']"/>
```

Comment: It's a very common mistake for people to assume that contains(X, Y) tests whether X is a sequence that contains the item Y. Don't try to guess what functions do from their name alone!

Answer (score 0):

i find workaround

```
<xsl:variable name="sources">
    <xsl:for-each select="distinct-values(root()//gml:edge/@source)">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/><xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
</xsl:for-each>
```

in this way, fn:contains works fine